# Unable to get list of updates

Tags: updates

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with MATE.  On running the gnome-software updater I get the message:

> "Unable to get list of updates:
> The name :1.121 was not provided by any .service files"

But it also tells me that "Software is up to date."
When running `sudo apt update` from a terminal it also tells me that all packages are up to date.

What is the cause of the error message?  Is it significant? How can I correct it?
Thank you.

Comment: Your description suggests that  gnome-software is having problems communicating with aptdaemon. If the issue persists after a reboot, please file a bug report. You can correct it only if you are familiar with how dBus works.

Comment: Please execute `sudo apt update` and `apt list --upgradable` in terminal and add its output to question if you have errors there.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. This problem persists after several reboots.  apt update and apt list --upgradable show no errors.  And no, I am not familiar with how dBus works.  I did submit this as a bug but it was rejected as "not a bug but a support request."

Answer (score 4):

i was getting a similar error: Unable to get list of updates: The name :1.122 was not provided by any .service files

i ended up fixing it buy running: `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software`

not sure if your supposed to do that but it worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Tried the gnome reinstall - did not help.